# What does "CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY" mean in Marketo?

Tags: marketo

Why do I get "CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY" in the name property for some results when I make a call to the lists API?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a permission issue, but you should elaborate on how your code looks like.

There could be some problem at FLS (Field Level Security) of Activity. Please make sure all fields of Activity, Task and Event (when used) are visible for the corresponding users and your used orgs. If there are any opportunity fields, they should be visible as well.